# Django: Put a Form into a Form (recursive ...)

Tags: python, django, forms, recursion, django-forms

I like Django forms library, but it would be even better if a form could contain forms.

My dream looks like this:

- I have a form which behaves like normal form: for example a class called `SuperForm`
- `SuperForm` can contain several normal forms, or even (recursive) `SuperForms`
- You can bind it to data (to make it bound), call `is_valid()` ...

Is this possible with django or an external app?

**Update**

I see many people did not understand what I want. My fault, I did not give a use case.

Use case: A page should allow the user to update his email and his telephone number. The email is from django.contrib.auth and the phone number is from our custom model.

Both inputs should be in a single `<form>` tag. Since `ModelForm` is easy to use, I don't want to create a form myself by hand.

I want a container which contains the `ModelForm` of django.contrib.auth.models.User and the `ModelForm` of our custom model.

I don't want to loop over both forms (in other use cases there could be much more forms) myself, and check whether they are valid or not.

If I call `is_valid()` or `save()` on the container the matching method of the forms gets called.

Comment: Dear user who down votes this question: Please tell my why you don't like it, and how it could be improved. Thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure you understand how forms work. Have you looked at the documentation for Formsets? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/forms/formsets/

Comment: @Johndt6 Formsets can only can N times the same form class. I want N different forms and recursion. AFAIK Formsets can't do this. Please tell me if I am wrong.

Comment: Are you wanting one form class to contain multi able forms that are callable? Or are you thinking of a class that you can generate with different options on the fly?

Comment: I believe this is possible (although it would be confusing and a lot of work). But why would you wan't to do this? What is the problem you wish to solve as there may be an easier way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should give it a try to [django-composite-form](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-composite-form). Whit this you will be able to write code like the following:

*Taken from the example distributed with the package*

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from composite_form.forms import CompositeForm
from example.models import Profile


class BaseProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        exclude = ("user")


class ProfileForm(CompositeForm):
    form_list = [UserCreationForm, BaseProfileForm]

    def clean_address(self):
        return "blah"

    def save(self, commit=True):
        if not self.is_valid():
            raise ValueError("Invalid form")
        user_form = self.get_form(UserCreationForm)
        user = user_form.save()
        profile_form = self.get_form(BaseProfileForm)
        profile_form.instance.user = user
        return profile_form.save()
```

Comment: I found that there are other form libraries which do something like this: https://www.djangopackages.com/grids/g/forms/ For example http://django-formfield.readthedocs.org/en/latest/getting_started.html

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure to understand what are you trying to achieve exactly but I had to solve a problem about dynamic forms once.

If you have **ONE** form (or `ModelForm` or whatever you need) you can initialize that form how many times as you need in your view.

If you have a form called `MyForm` you can do in your view like:

```
...        ...
form1 = MyForm(...)
form2 = MyForm(...)
form3 = MyForm(...)
...         ...
```

and you could send all of them to templates.

This number of forms **has no need** to be static, you can add a number of "dynamic" forms into a list and send the list of forms to template and manage there as you need.

It will be better for you and the people who try to help you if you explain a little more about your situation and why are you trying to achieve this, because maybe my answer is useless for you.

Anyway I strongly recommend you to check [Django FormSets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/formsets/) because is the best way to generate/manage dynamic forms in one template

---

In wich situation could you need this kind of "dynamic" forms ?

What kind of information are you trying to get ?

Are you trying to create objects dynamically ?

Are you trying to have a number of forms depending on some information ?

How are you going to manage this "dynamic" forms in your template/view ?

Answer (score 0):

In first glance, your idea seems to be complex. And the immediate question is - "Why do need such feature?". 99% - of tasks can be solved with built-in Django "bricks", another 1% - "Please hardcode". Also I may assume that the problem behind such an idea is complex too, and will be hard understandable by end user.

Answer (score -1):

I think you are thinking about forms in a different way than what you should.

Forms are simply there for input. How they are processed is up to you.

Sure you can run is_valid on the form, and that would check against the modelform that you have assigned. The awesome thing is you can check multiple model forms on the same form. The data that is needed for the model form will be processed the extra data would be ignored. If the is_valid fails you still pass the data back like you normally would to be corrected.

Comment: For those that have marked this down, my answer is still valid - although I didn't give an example code what I wrote is still true. You can have multiple forms within the same <form> tag that is processed by multiple model forms at the same time. ModelForm just depends on the input "name" attribute to match the elements you are trying to process in your model form.

Comment: I didn't voted down your answer, but I want explain something to you. If your answer is voted down, its not personal (trust me I suffered already) its just the community ranking your answer according to the question. Yes it is important your answer match the question, for example (an extreme one) even if is true, what you think if you ask me: *"Hey how can I wrote code for make coffe?"* and my answer is: *"Yes dude, the sky is blue!"* thats true but, how you vote that answer? Up or down?